# Using an image included in project

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, image

I've added an image `logo.bmp` into my project, but I can't figure out how to assign it to an `Image` type. I've started by creating the variabale:

```
public static Image logo { get; set; }
```

but I can't figure out how to assign my image to it. This is what I have right now:

```
logo = Image.FromFile("logo.bmp");
```

But that assumes the image is in the directory of the .exe. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream` to load a resource from a loaded assembly.

First you must make sure that the file in your Visual Studio project is actually being embedded in the assembly itself.  Right click on the file and select **Properties**, then make sure that **Build Action** is **Embedded Resource**.

Now you can call `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream` from code in that same assembly and specify the resource name with a fully qualified namespace, such as `"YourSolution.YourProject.Images.logo.bmp"`.

The `Image` class you are using has a method to load from a stream called `Image.FromStream()`.

So here is a code snippet of what you might do:

```
Image image;

var stream = Asssembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("MySolution.MyProject.Images.logo.bmp");

image = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

Just keep in mind that you may need to dispose the stream separately from the image when loaded this way.

Comment: Is a namespace required for Assembely.x? I don't see the class in intellisense

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention it's an instance method.  You must specify *which* assembly to load the resource from.  There are lots of different ways of finding an assembly... but in most cases `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` works.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite getting the assembely thing. I'm really new to C#, so I don't know what exactly it means. Where would I find my assembely name?

Comment: If you type the name of the class and right click on it in Visual Studio it would give you an option to "Resolve".  It can write out the full name for you or it can add a `using` statement so you can use a shorter form of the name.

Comment: If you google the class name you can find a page like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.aspx) which will tell you the name of the .dll you need and the fully qualified namespace.  In this case you don't really need to look that up because the `Assembly` class is part of the core .NET framework and you shouldn't need to add any DLLs to reference it, you already have those DLLs referenced.

Answer (score 0):

The Assembly class is part of the System.Reflection namespace. An alternative for using Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() is

```
typeof(YourClassName).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("path.to.your.resource")
```

This way you can use a type to determine from which assembly you would like to access a resource.

Comment: So something like this? 

    `logo = typeof(Program).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("POS_System.POS_System.Images.logo.bmp");`